# Website/forum about reviews for universities

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate, university

Is there any website/forum that people share their experiences or personal opinions in their university?

I find it hard to get reviews other than rankings made by large companies that provide useful information about whether it is a good place for obtaining a degree.

Comment: Your best source might be people who you know (of) who went to different places. I would say, in general, that any on-line review forums are heavily weighted towards bad experiences, so take anything you read on line with a large grain of salt.

Comment: Your question has tags both for "graduate-school" and "undergraduate" - what are you interested in evaluating universities for?

Comment: @BryanKrause I wanted to make the question more general since I assumed such website would include information about programme of all degrees.

Comment: The answer would likely vastly differ for graduate vs. undegraduate.

Answer (score 3):

The only website I am personally familiar with is [Rate My Professor](https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/) (RMP). It is used primarily to rate professors of Universities, but it also allows students to rate their institution.

I am not affiliated with Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT) but I am a Computer Science professor so here are [the reviews of MIT](https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/school/580) as an example.

RMP does include Universities from around the globe but I do not know how many countries or Universities they actually include.